# Understanding Spark Scala basic method invocation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to make sense of the following code snippet.  I think this more of a Scala than a Spark question...

```
    val links = sc.textFile("../../data/links.csv")

    val linksRDD: RDD[Edge[Connexion]] = links map {line => 
        val row = line split ','
        Edge(row(0).toInt, row(1).toInt, row(2))
    }
```

I am used to seeing the following type of idiom in regards to calling the Spark map() function on an RDD:

```
 links.map{line => val fields = line.split(","); val f1 = x._1; (f1, "stuff)}
```

My question is: that I cannot understand the construct:

```
 val row = line split ','
```

All the (very limited) Spark examples that I so far see following the pattern:

```
 val row = line.split(',')
```

I feel as though in rushing through my basic Spark tutorials in order to get to Scala, that I have missed something rather basic.

Can somebody please tell me what I have missed...?

Thanks

Comment: You are correct @pedrofurla this is a duplicate.  The question that you linked to is probably more comprehensively framed and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scala` has a special punctuation-free syntax for invoking methods that **take one argument** which is called `infix` notations so:

```
line.split(',')
```

is equivalent to:

```
line split ','
```

Comment: Thanks heaps @Ramesh.  So if a method takes more than 1 argument I have to use the second construct...?

Comment: yes you got it right.

Comment: @markthekoala: I am quite surprised that you have never seen punctuation-free syntax in Scala before, e.g. something like `1 + 2`.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag.   I have not seen  `line split ','` before but certainly have seen `line.split(',')`

According to  http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html suggest that `line.split(',')` is preffered.  

And contrary to @Ramesh 's initial answer it also appears that the syntax `line.split(',')` can be used when the method accepts more than one parameter.